# ServiceStack service metadata shows no operations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack for the first time on a brand-new project that started off as a ASP.NET MVC. I am hosting ServiceStack API at the root, so my web.config looks like this:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

and my App_Start/RouteConfig.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("*");
}
```

Here's my service:

```
[Route("/catalogs/{ID}")]
[DataContract]
public class CatalogRequest : IReturn<Catalog>
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

[DefaultView("Catalogs")]
public class CatalogService : Service
{
    public object Get(CatalogRequest request)
    {
        return (request.ID == 9999) ? new Catalog() { ID = 9999 } : null;
    }
}
```

I use the following for testing:

```
public class TestAppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public TestAppHost() : base("TestService", typeof(TestAppHost).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
    {
        IoC.Configure(container); // IoC is where all Funq configuration is done
    }
}
```

In my VisualStudio unit test I start up the AppHost like this:

```
[TestClass]
public class TestHelper
{
    public const string TEST_HOST_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8888/";

    private static TestAppHost __AppHost;

    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void Initialize(TestContext context)
    {
        // Start the test app host.
        __AppHost = new TestAppHost();
        __AppHost.Init();
        __AppHost.Start(TEST_HOST_URL);
    }

    [AssemblyCleanup]
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        __AppHost.Dispose();
        __AppHost = null;
    }
}
```

When I run my test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RequestCatalogByID()
{
    var client = new JsonServiceClient(TestHelper.TEST_HOST_URL);
    var request = new CatalogRequest() { ID = 9999 };
    var response = client.Get(request);

    Assert.IsNotNull(response);
}
```

I get a "Not Found" exception even though the URL seems to be correct: `http://127.0.0.1:8888/catalogs/9999`.

Pointing the browser to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/metadata` shows the metadata page with no operations.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the assembly you pass in your AppHost Base constructor should be where all your service implementations are (i.e. not your AppHost), so try instead:

```
public class TestAppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public TestAppHost() : base("TestService", typeof(CatalogService).Assembly){}
    ...
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. The Service is in the same project than the AppHostBase.